# Google Drive Api (V2) `corpora` choices

Tags: google-drive-api

### What are the possible choices for `corpora` and what do they mean?

I want to get a list of all the files I have access too inside a directory, Using `.files().list( ... )`

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

I used to run the following code which worked:

```
SearchParameterString = "'" + FolderId + "' in parents"
#NOTE there is a return limit of 460 files (falsly documented as 1000)
DriveFileItems = []
PageToken = None
while True:
    try:
        DriveFilesObject = Service.files().list(
            q           = SearchParameterString,
            #corpora     = 'domain', #'default',#SearchOwners, 
            corpus     = 'DOMAIN',  #----> DEPRICATED!!! 
            maxResults  = 200,
            pageToken   = PageToken,
            ).execute()

        DriveFileItems.extend(DriveFilesObject['items'])
        PageToken = DriveFilesObject.get('nextPageToken')
        if not PageToken:
            break
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
        break
```

And the above code broke for me on June 25. With the following error message:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27___myFolderIdHere___%27+in+parents&alt=json&corpus=DOMAIN&maxResults=200 returned "Invalid query">

And I figured out that it was because they deprecated parameter `corpus` in favor of `corpora`

What are the possible choices for google drive api `corpora` ? 
And what do they mean?

```
corpora = 'domain',   #DOES NOT WORK
```

How do I make sure I am getting the full list of files, instead of just the files I own? (previously I had to switch from `DEFAULT` to `DOMAIN` because I had all sorts of problems from not getting full file lists, and ended up uploading many many duplicates while trying to use drive api to sync directories across machines)

I found this:
    https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/issues/218

and this:
    https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/jwt#Config

but don't really know what it means to impersonate a user, nor do I really think I want to do so.

EDIT: I happen to be using python - but the question is language agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using drive api v2:

`corpora = 'domain'`  doesn't work at all...

`corpus = 'DOMAIN'` doesn't work at all...

`corpora = 'default'`  seems to do the trick.

`corpora = 'default'` works now the same way  `corpus = 'DOMAIN'` worked before.

Files created by other users are not omitted (as I desire). Google changed this functionality without announcing it, and it broke out of nowhere for me on June 25, 2017.

Comment: ... and also poorly documented it at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Answer (score 2):

I think you can see that in the [Migrate from Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration), the only options are:

```
Method       Parameter         Alternative 
files.list  corpus=DEFAULT  corpus=user
files.list  corpus=DOMAIN   corpus=domain
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Google Drive Java API, then most portably you are missing one of following arguments:

- drive_id
- include_items_from_all_drives=true
- supports_all_drives=true
- corpora=drive

Specifying those arguments is especially important in case you want to find files only from one shared drive.

```
    private void readFiles(Drive drive) {
    FileList result;
    try {
        result = drive.files().list()
                      .setQ("'" + DOCUMENTS_FOLDER_ID + "' in parents")
                      .setDriveId(P10_DRIVE_ID)
                      .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
                      .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                      .setCorpora("drive")
                      .setPageSize(100)
                      .setFields("nextPageToken,files(id, name, webViewLink)")
                      .execute();

        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s) (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId(), file.getWebViewLink());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the right resource with this information: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-files#org.

In summary, the `corpora` value can be:

- `user` — Includes all files created by and opened by the user in "My Drive", and those shared directly with the user in "Shared with me."
- `drive` — Includes all files contained in a single shared drive, as indicated by the driveId.
- `domain` — Includes all searchable files shared with the user's domain.
- `allDrives` — Includes all files in shared drives where the user is a member, and all files in "My Drive" and "Shared with me." Use the allDrives corpora with caution as it has a broad scope and can affect performance. When possible, use user or drive instead of allDrives for efficiency.